# Is there a convention for named arguments in a function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I come from a SQL Server background where the '@' symbol is used/encouraged in stored procedures. This is useful because you can easily see what is a column and what is a value. For example.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Foo
    @Bar    VARCHAR(10),
    @Baz    INT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyTable (
        Bar,
        Baz)
    VALUES (
        @Bar,
        @Baz)

END
```

I know that I can just use ordinal position but some of our stored procs have 20 or so parameters and the named parameter makes it much more legible IMO.

Is there some sort of convention that the PostgreSQL communitiy uses for a prefix? I tried to find out exactly what the rules were for named parameters but my Googling didn't yield anything.

Comment: I want to know what the naming convention is for named parameters or how people avoid column name and value ambiguity. We have some stored procedures with 20 parameters and it would be painful to work with $1, $17 etc etc

Comment: In Oracle PL/SQL one very widely used convention is `p_`-prefix. (The question was originally wrongly labelled.)

Comment: I have started experimenting with affixing `$` to my variable names, such as `foo$`. It’s not as clear as the MSSQL `@foo`, but it does follow a pattern, and is readable. Personally I find a naming convention like `p_foo` to be tedious and less readable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Parameter identifiers follow the same rules as other identifiers:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTION-ARGUMENTS

It is common to start a parameter identifier with an underscore `_` and I think it makes sense although it is not a convention.

It is also possible to avoid ambiguity by qualifying the identifier with the function name

```
my_funtion.my_parameter
```

Comment: I also picked on underscore without knowing. I really didn't want to have to repeat the function name repeatedly.

Comment: I like underscores underscore too, because most databases get very confused when parameter names clash with table column names (assuming no one has been misguided enough to name columns with leading underscores - I have seen it done)