# Naming convention for parameters in stored procedures in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, parameters

Is there a naming convention for parameters for stored procedures in postgres? I wanted to distinguish my parameters from my column names to make it easier to read, so student_id (column) = s_id(parameter), period (column) = per (parameter name), assignment (column) = asgmt (parameter), ect..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 
    insert_assignment(s_id INT, per INT, cl VARCHAR(50), ln VARCHAR(50), sp_id INT, asgmt VARCHAR(500))
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    INSERT INTO 
        assignment(sped_id, assignment)
    VALUES
        (sp_id, asgmt);
    UPDATE assignment ss
    SET student_schedule_id= 
        (SELECT
            ss.student_schedule_id
            FROM 
                student_schedule ss
            LEFT JOIN
                class_teacher ct on ct.class_teacher_id=ss.class_teacher_id
            LEFT JOIN
                teacher t on t.teacher_id=ct.teacher_id
            LEFT JOIN
                class c on c.class_id=ct.class_id
            WHERE
                ss.student_id=s_id AND ss.period=per
        )
    WHERE assignment=asgmt
$$
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a well-established convention.  The closest thing I've found so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119622/is-there-a-convention-for-named-arguments-in-a-function-in-postgresql), so feel free to establish your own convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing established conventions but there are 2 common themes I seen. But first on either do not truncate parameter names this actually makes reading and understanding them harder; also allign them instead of just stringing them out. The most common is to preference the parameter as p_ . The other is to suffix parameter with its usage an  _in or _ot  
 Examples:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 
   insert_assignment(p_student_id INT, p_period INT, p_cl VARCHAR(50), p_ln VARCHAR(50), p_sped_id INT, p_assignment VARCHAR(500))
LANGUAGE SQL ...

or 

CREATE PROCEDURE  
   insert_assignment(student_id_in INT, 
                     period_in INT,
                     cl_in VARCHAR(50),
                     ln_in VARCHAR(50), 
                     sped_id_in INT,
                     assignment_in VARCHAR(500)
                    )
    LANGUAGE SQL ...
```

Not sure about cl,ln as you did not use them. As for sepd if it is in common use in your organization it is fine otherwise (IMHO) it is a poor name. Make understanding your primary goal, not less typing. (and this from a very poor typist)

Comment: What does the suffix _in and _ot stand for?

Comment: Indicates the usage of the parameter. Exp. User_name as IN parameter would be user_name_in; as an OUT parameter would be user_name_ot; as an INOUT parameter would be user_name_io.